# Three.JS Help Loading GLTF Models

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm learning THREE.JS using a tutorial. I am struggling with getting my GLTF model loaded. It's not showing up in the browser. Do I need to create 2 scenes? One for my background and one for my model? There are no console errors either that I can work with. I checked with another stack overflow post that talked about this similar issue and they talked about implementing an animate function, but I have already included this.

```
var canvas, renderer, scene, camera, particle, loader;

window.onload = function() {
  init();
  animate();

}

function init() {
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true });
  renderer.setPixelRatio((window.devicePixelRatio) ? window.devicePixelRatio 
  : 1);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  renderer.autoClear = false;
  renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0.0);
  document.getElementById('canvas').appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / 
  window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
  camera.position.z = 400;
  scene.add(camera);


  var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
  loader.load('models/scene.glb', function(gltf){
    let model = gltf.scene
    let child = model.children[0]
    model.scale.x = model.scale.y = model.scale.z = 0.15;
    model.castShadow = true;
    model.receiveShadow = true;
    model.position.y = -0.5;

    scene.add(model);
  }, undefined, function (error){
    console.error(error);
  });


  var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xffffff,
    shading: THREE.FlatShading
  });

  particle = new THREE.Object3D();
  scene.add(particle);
  var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(2, 12, 12);

  for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.position.set(Math.random() - 0.5, Math.random() - 0.5, Math.random() 
    - 0.5).normalize();
    mesh.position.multiplyScalar(90 + (Math.random() * 700));
    mesh.rotation.set(Math.random() * 2, Math.random() * 2, Math.random() * 
    2);
    particle.add(mesh);
  }

  var mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xffffff,
    shading: THREE.FlatShading
  });

  var mat2 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xffffff,
    wireframe: true,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide

  });


  var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x999999 );
  scene.add(ambientLight);

  var lights = [];
  lights[0] = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1 );
  lights[0].position.set( 1, 0, 0 );
  lights[1] = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0x11E8BB, 1 );
  lights[1].position.set( 0.75, 1, 0.5 );
  lights[2] = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0x8200C9, 1 );
  lights[2].position.set( -0.75, -1, 0.5 );
  scene.add( lights[0] );
  scene.add( lights[1] );
  scene.add( lights[2] );


  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

};

function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  particle.rotation.x += 0.0000;
  particle.rotation.y -= 0.0040;

  renderer.clear();

  renderer.render( scene, camera )
};
```

Comment: Try checking the network tab of dev tools to make sure it is loading

Comment: A lot of this depends on what's on your `.glb` file. Use `console.log()` to make sure the callback is being triggered when it loads. Secondly, your `.glb` object could be too big (so the camera is inside it) or too small (it might be rendering behind something), or out of view (maybe it's 1000 units off in the x-axis)... it's impossible to tell exactly what's going on without a live example.